# Why is "std::is_pointer<std::nullptr_t>::value" equal to false?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, pointers, nullptr

I read about `std::is_pointer` in C++.

Then I wrote the program and check whether `T` is a pointer type or not using `std::is_pointer`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::cout<<std::boolalpha;
    std::cout<<"char : " <<std::is_pointer<char>::value<<std::endl; // OK
    std::cout<<"char * : "<<std::is_pointer<char *>::value<<std::endl; // OK
    std::cout<<"char ** : "<<std::is_pointer<char **>::value<<std::endl; // OK
    std::cout<<"char *** : "<<std::is_pointer<char ***>::value<<std::endl; // OK
    std::cout<<"std::nullptr_t : "<<std::is_pointer<std::nullptr_t>::value<<std::endl;  // Not ok, Why false??
}
```

**Output** : [[Wandbox Demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5EoGQzKPdObB7NcF)

```
char : false
char * : true
char ** : true
char *** : true
std::nullptr_t : false
```

Why is `std::is_pointer<std::nullptr_t>::value` equal to `false`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because `std::nullptr_t` is *not a pointer type*. And `is_pointer` only evaluates to `true` for pointer types.

`nullptr_t` is convertible to a pointer, but it *isn't* a pointer. Indeed, `nullptr_t` is not a class type, integral, floating-point, enumerator, or any kind of type other than `is_null_pointer` type. It has its own unique classification in the categorization of types.

Comment: Any Idea about the rational behind that design decision?

Comment: @MikeMB Yeah, so it is not accidentally deduced as anything else in template overload resolution. having int `0` being a null pointer content was a mess

Comment: `nullptr_t` is *not* a class type? Is that explicitly mandated? [lex.nullptr] only states that it is not a pointer type.

Comment: @M.M: I absolutely agree that the special semantics of `0`are very problematic, but I would have imagined / hoped that `nullptr` could be it's own type, but that type would be a pointer type (just like `void*` is a pointer type with some special semantics).

Comment: @MikeMB: The problem with that would be that `template <typename T> void f(T*); f(nullptr)` would then be valid. Currently, if you want to allow that call, you must add an overload `void f(std::nullptr_t)` but that overload can forward to e.g. `f<void*>`.  However, if `nullptr` was a pointer type and you did _not_ want it, removing it from the oveload set would be more complicated.

Comment: @Quentin: "*Is that explicitly mandated?*" Yes. It is listed in [basic.fundamental], so it cannot be a class type. And `is_null_pointer` is a primary type category; for any type `T`, only *one* of the primary category traits will be true.

Answer (score 9):

Because it's not a pointer type. It's a distinct type that is implicitly convertible to any pointer type.

As the note in [[lex.nullptr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.nullptr#1) summarizes:

> The pointer literal is the keyword nullptr. It is a prvalue of type
>   std​::​nullptr_­t. [ Note: std​::​nullptr_­t is a distinct type that
>   is neither a pointer type nor a pointer to member type; rather, a
>   prvalue of this type is a null pointer constant and can be converted
>   to a null pointer value or null member pointer value. See [conv.ptr]
>   and [conv.mem].  — end note ]

Answer (score 6):

As unintuitive as it sounds, `std::nullptr_t` is not a pointer type. For instance, [you cannot dereference a `std::nullptr_t`](https://godbolt.org/g/uUihH8), so it'd be pretty weird if `is_pointer_type<nullptr_t>::value` was `true`.

It is merely convertible to any pointer type.

Comment: it not being dereferenceable its the first argument I've heard that actually makes sense and carries a real weight.

Comment: @bolov, zneak: You can't dereference a `void *` either though.

Answer (score 4):

Because [std::nullptr_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t) is not a pointer type itself, but the type of the null pointer literal `nullptr`.

> `std::nullptr_t` is the type of the null pointer literal, `nullptr`. It is a distinct type that is not itself a pointer type or a pointer to member type.

From the standard, [21.2.3 Null pointers [support.types.nullptr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/support.types.nullptr#1)

> The type `nullptr_­t` is a synonym for the type of a `nullptr` expression, and it has the characteristics described in [basic.fundamental] and [conv.ptr].

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely unintuitive in some cases, but it makes sense:

1. Value-wise, it doesn't behave like a pointer; it cannot *point to anything*.
   For example, you cannot do

   ```
   T *p = ...;
   reinterpret_cast<T *>(reinterpret_cast<std::nullptr_t>(p));
   ```

   and expect to get a pointer to the same address that `p` points to.
2. Type-wise, it doesn't behave like a pointer. For example,

   ```
   std::is_pointer<P>::value
   ```

   should imply

   ```
   std::is_same<P, std::remove_pointer<P>::type *>::value
   ```

   but that clearly isn't the case.